# Powerpoint obj customization

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to resize the "rectangle" Object in the power point depending on the excel data in a cell using excel vba? if yes please tell me some steps to process it

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes, the rectangle is a shape object which has properties like top, left and width. For further details look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/object-model-powerpoint-vba-reference) for PP